# How to split up a map string using Regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

In the system I work on there is some legacy code that I would love to change, but can't. This code is storing values in a map which looks like the following string:

```
userId: "929290"; name: "Donnie Darko"; obj : {field1: "field"; field2: "field2"} phone: "666-6666";
```

Notice that the object map isn't followed by a semicolon, but every other key/value pair is. Is there a way to use Regex in Java and get the first level of this map, so that I could have:

```
userId: "929290"
obj : {field1: "field"; field2: "field2"}
```

I only want the first level, I'm not looking to parse out field1 and field2 individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure of the use case here, but here are the regexes to help you find it

```
 Pattern userIdPattern = Pattern.compile("^userId:\\s*\"(\\d+)\";.*$"); // will be the userId number
 Pattern objPattern = Pattern.compile(".*(obj\\s*:\\s*\{[^\}]+\}).*"); //will be the JSON object inside
 Matcher userIdMatcher = userIdPattern.matcher("userId: \"929290\"; name: \"Donnie Darko\"; obj : {field1: \"field\"; field2: \"field2\"} phone: \"666-6666\";");
 if(userIdMatcher.find()){
     System.out.println("userId : " + .group(1));
 }
 Matcher objPatternMatcher = objPattern.matcher("userId: \"929290\"; name: \"Donnie Darko\"; obj : {field1: \"field\"; field2: \"field2\"} phone: \"666-6666\";");
 if(objPatternMatcher.find()){
     System.out.println(objPatternMatcher.group(1));
 }
```

Comment: one thing i should mention is that it is physically impossible to use a regex to traverse a nested hierarchy. If there are any nested JSON objects under 'obj', it will not work. You could modify the regex to deal with this, but you'll need to do it for every level down.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of using [ANTLR](http://WWW.ANTLR.ORG)?  It is a language recognizer which is much more powerful than a regex.  That way, you could deal with composite fields (e.g. `{field1: {field3:"field3"; field4="field4"}; field2: "field2"}`)  The learning curve is steeper than that of learning regexes though; but, in my opinion, learning ANTLR is worth it.

Comment: If you need to actually do proper interpretation, antlr's definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

looks like a JSON string... you can use JSON :)

Comment: It's actually close, but not close enough. It's more of a list than a map, and if I tried to parse that as JSON it would explode.

Comment: @stevebot A few simple string replacements might get you to valid json.

Comment: those string replacements would be complex enough, that I might aswell just Regex it to get the data.